# How to split values in Azure Data Factory: CSV to SQL

Tags: sql, azure, csv, azure-data-factory

Is it possible to split the column values in Azure Data Factory? I am wanting to split a value in a column from a CSV into a SQL table. I am wanting to keep the second value "Training Programmes Manager" in the same column deleting the 1st and 3rd and the 4th value "Education" moved to an already made column in SQL

Value separated by |

Image of value below:

[Value in CSV](https://i.stack.imgur.com/auJ0X.png)

Thanks James

Comment: Hi James - can you add some detail? Is this a Pipe delimited file, or are these values in a single column of a larger CSV file?

Comment: Hi Joel - The value shown in the image is in a single column in a large CSV file.

Answer (score 0):

Since you need to work with a particular column value, you'll need to use a Data Flow.

1. Source: Create a DataSet for your CSV file.
2. In the Data Flow, use Derived Column to parse the | delimited column into new columns.
3. Sink to SQL, referencing the new column names.

Comment: For Joel's step 2 above, you should look at using the split() function here which will give you an array of values split on the vertical bar.

Comment: How do you reference the column name in `split()`? For a string, you can simply use `split(“extract me by spaces”, “ “)`. But how do you reference a column value?